# href not working when tring to redirect it to another page

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, bootstrap-4

> I am tring to give a href tag to an option which will take to another
> page .All the other options are directing to the different part of the
> page itself.When i put   
>
> [CONTACT](/contact.html)
>
>  it is not working.All the
> files are in the same folder .So i guess there is no problem with the
> root. is it due to css ? how to solve it ?
>
> LINK SOLUTIONS-->
>
> HOME
>
> ABOUT
>
> SERVICE
>
> PORTFOLIO
>
> [CONTACT](/contact)

Comment: Please show your code so we can understand what you are trying to solve. Add more information to your post. The 'href` you provided is re-directing to `/contact` route. So if it's not `redirecting`, check your routes and controller if you are using node.js

Answer (score 1):

Please use this syntax if you are using HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="/about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li><a href="/service.html">SERVICE</a></li>
  <li><a href="/portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
  <li><a href="/contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```